# Adding JSON data in audit table

Tags: sqlalchemy, audit-tables

I am creating audit tables for my database using `sqlalchemy-postgresql-audit` but the issue is that it creates a separate `audit_table` for every table and I wan't to create a common `audit_table` for all which contains

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| transaction(insertion/updation/deletion) |      data.    |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have edited the source code to create a common table for all by `extend_existing=True` and I wan't to add the the data of `transacted` row as `JSON` in `data`.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for this 
When trigger is applies a `RECORD` for the `OLD` `ROW` in case of `UPDATION` and `DELETION` and `NEW` `ROW` in case of `UPDATION` and `INSERTION` is created i.e we can access values using

```
OLD.(column_name) or NEW.(column_name)
```

And to enter the entire `ROW` as `JSON` in `data` field

```
to_json(NEW) or to_json(OLD)
```

will work